# MySQL INSERT query works but Data is not inserted

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I just want to insert into database, but following code is not showing any error nor showing my inserted data in database. Can anybody help me in debugging this code.

```
<?php
$tips = $_POST["tips"];
$day = $_POST["day"];
$month = $_POST["month"];
$year = $_POST["year"];
$date = $year."-".$month."-".$day;

//echo "$date: $tips";

//========================
//  DataBase Connectivity
//========================
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","mydb");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to Database";
    exit;
  }

else{
// Perform INSERT query
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO daily_tips (PublishingDate,Tips) VALUES ('$date','$tips')");
    echo "data inserted"
    exit;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: try `echo "INSERT INTO daily_tips (PublishingDate,Tips) VALUES ('$date','$tips')";` and show your output here

Comment: hackers heaven here!!! sanitize your posts or you are into big trouble. or try to use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
if( mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO daily_tips (PublishingDate,Tips) VALUES ('$date','$tips')"))
{
    echo 'success';
}else{
    echo 'failed';
}
```

Comment: can anyone explain downvote and why it is bad to check query is executed?

Answer (score 1):

Make Sure your date format is like this '2013-12-05' ($date = $year."-".$month."-".$day)

and try this code:

mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO daily_tips (`PublishingDate`,`Tips`) VALUES('".$date."','".$tips."')");
echo "data inserted";
exit;

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO daily_tips (PublishingDate,Tips) VALUES ('".$date."','".$tips."')");
```

Comment: what is the error? or you try with mysql_query insterad of mysqli_query

Answer (score 0):

first of all you do not need to provide else condition remove "else" block

if everything is ok above then try this:

```
 $sql= mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO daily_tips (PublishingDate,Tips) VALUES  ('".$date."','".$tips."')");

 if( $sql) {
 echo "data inserted";
 } else {
 echo "not inserted";
 }
```

Comment: why are you introducing unnecessary complication in string concatenation?

Comment: this is not complication,,, it will parse your data in right way , wheather it is int type or string type ..

Comment: you have tried my code ,, is there occuring any error , please let me know

Comment: what is wrong with `"INSERT INTO daily_tips (PublishingDate,Tips) VALUES  ('$date','$tips')"`? isnt it more readable and less prone to errors?

Comment: actully when we insert data, then we should make sure that our data is parse correctly in comparision to thier data type.

Comment: Use double quotes to concat more than two strings instead of multiple '.' operators.  PHP is forced to re-concatenate with every '.' operator.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the complete code and let me know, its working fine for me and let me know what the data type you are using for PublishingDate ?

```
<?php
$tips = "Today tips";
$day = "12";
$month = "01";
$year = "2012";
$date = $year."-".$month."-".$day;

//echo "$date: $tips";

//========================
//  DataBase Connectivity
//========================
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","test");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno($con))
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to Database";
    exit;
  }

else{
// Perform INSERT query
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO daily_tips (PublishingDate,Tips) VALUES ('$date','$tips')");
    echo "data inserted";
    exit;
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```